# How I can select and open a file from given path in PhpStorm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm

At VSCode (and VSCodium) by pressing `Ctrl+P` I am able to open a file via a given relative path to the project.

How I can have this functionality in PhpStorm as well?

What I want is a similar functionality to this:

[image: Prompt to select a file in VSCode]